# Chrome закрывается после browser.get

Tags: google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, webbrowser, webdriver

Chrome закрывается после такой простой отработки.

```
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Chrome(r"C:\chromedriver\chromedriver.exe")

browser.get('https://www.google.ru/')
```

выдает такое

```
DeprecationWarning: executable_path has been deprecated, please pass in a Service object
  browser = webdriver.Chrome(r"C:\chromedriver\chromedriver.exe")
```

путь выставлен правильно, пробовал разные варианты с папками и выкладыванием файла. Добавление\изменение PATH никак не помогает

Answer (score 0):

поможет

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

chrome_driver_path = '/usr/bin/chromedriver'
service = Service(chrome_driver_path)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service)
```